# Having trouble with sprintf function and string class

Tags: arduino-uno, string

in my code, I was using string class to make an array to store my menu items

```
String menu[2] = {{"Menu 1"}, {"Menu2"}};
```

How do I convert this into char arrays and how do I call them?

```
Example:
Serial.println(menu[0]);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for menu[0].c_str()

Comment: `const char* menu[2] = {"Menu 1", "Menu2"};`

Comment: By the way, you can access a string.  You call a function.  You don't call a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create them as char arrays like this:

```
const char* menu[2] = {"Menu 1", "Menu 2"};
```

and use them like this:

```
Serial.println(menu[0]);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it's an array of `char*`, not an array of `char`. And you should handle "Menu 1" as a `const char*`, to allow the compiler inhibit you doing nonsense. And avoid `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]`

Comment: Edited for the const.

Comment: It is an array of char*.  And each one of those pointers points to a char array, not a String.  My point there was to distinguish between char array and String object.

Comment: Agreed. Even the warning text calls "hello" a `string constant`. But `string` (string literals aka const char array) and `Arduino String Objects` are so different that we should avoid using the term *string* completely.